# Ubuntu 18.04 won't boot when LVM volumes are cached

Tags: boot, raid, lvm, lvmcache

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 PC with the following disk layout :

```
======================

lsblk
NAME                MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                   8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk  
└─sda1                8:1    0 931,5G  0 part  
  └─md0               9:0    0 931,4G  0 raid1 
    ├─lvraid0-root  253:0    0   9,3G  0 lvm   /
    ├─lvraid0-usr   253:1    0  26,4G  0 lvm   /usr
    ├─lvraid0-boot  253:2    0   952M  0 lvm   /boot
    ├─lvraid0-var   253:3    0  27,1G  0 lvm   /var
    ├─lvraid0-local 253:4    0     3G  0 lvm   /usr/local
    └─lvraid0-home  253:5    0 801,9G  0 lvm   /home
sdb                   8:16   1  28,9G  0 disk  
├─sdb1                8:17   1     2G  0 part  /media/jan/Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS amd
└─sdb2                8:18   1   2,4M  0 part  
sdc                   8:32   0 931,5G  0 disk  
└─sdc1                8:33   0 931,5G  0 part  
  └─md0               9:0    0 931,4G  0 raid1 
    ├─lvraid0-root  253:0    0   9,3G  0 lvm   /
    ├─lvraid0-usr   253:1    0  26,4G  0 lvm   /usr
    ├─lvraid0-boot  253:2    0   952M  0 lvm   /boot
    ├─lvraid0-var   253:3    0  27,1G  0 lvm   /var
    ├─lvraid0-local 253:4    0     3G  0 lvm   /usr/local
    └─lvraid0-home  253:5    0 801,9G  0 lvm   /home
sdd                   8:48   0 238,5G  0 disk  
├─sdd1                8:49   0    64G  0 part  [SWAP]
└─sdd2                8:50   0 174,5G  0 part  

===================
```

In order to speed up disk access I configured `lvm2` to use `/dev/sdd2` (SSD) as a cache volume using `lvmcache`.  I first tried caching all lvm volumes. That did not go well.

During `update-grub` there ware a lot of errors which disappeard when I removed the cache on boot volume.  After this I did a `update-initramfs -u -k all` and `update-grub and all`, looked well and the caching worked like a charm with impressive speed.

Now boot - disaster !  No boot.  I got some messages that the kernel did not support caching or something like that, and complaints that the boot process could not connect to `lvmetad` (it complained about even before, but lvm scanning found lvm volumes).

Luckily I ended up in an `initramfs` busybox.  I had never heard of that before, but it had an lvm command that allowed me to use regular lv- type commands like `lvremove` and after removing cache volumes I was able to boot.

To make a long story relatively short, I tried to limit lvm caching to only one of volumes (not boot) but in all cases booting failed in some way.
Now as shown in the `lsblk` output, I have a raid1 disk `/dev/md0` made from two seagate hdds, and on top of that I have created a number of lvm volumes.

I would hope someone have a trick up their sleeve to enable the lvm cache to boot - and if possible also fix the `lvmetad` boot problem.  I should add that I also tried to add modules to `initramfs` via `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`.  I added `dm-cache.ko` and it may have changed the boot problem nature (I dont have an exact description)

Answer (score 0):

After some intensive googling I have found a solution.

Essentially the problem comes down to Ubuntu 18.04 initramfs framework is missing important components and configurations.  You need to do the following :

sudo apt update

sudo apt upgrade

apt install initramfs-tools thin-provisioning toools

(in addition to LVM2 of course)

Then you have to follow this recipe to fix the initramfs shortcomings in Ubuntu 18.04

http://scyu.logdown.com/posts/519001-ubuntu-lvmcache-setup

configure your lvmcach in accordans with manpage for lvmcache

sudo update-initramfs -u -k all

sudo update-grub2

reboot and enjoy !

The result is amazing.  It's like I have a speed daemon now on a 5 year old PC :-)